# onkeydown / onkeypress html and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

it has been a month since i have started web languages (HTML, javascript, PHP) and today i am asked to create a subscription page....
i was able to change the color of an input text box into red if the mandatory field was empty, problem is : i want it to be white again when i click on a key when i type something in it...
here is my test code (a little program to understand how certain commands work):

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT>
function check()
{
    var value;
    value = document.test.Secondary_Key.value;
    if (value.length < 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("Secondary_Key").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
function colorbox()
{
    var values;
    values = document.test.Secondary_key.value;
    if (values.length > 0)
        document.getElementById("Secondary_Key").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</SCRIPT>
<FORM name = test>
<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TD align = right>Secondary key<input type="text" size="35" maxlength="256" name="Secondary_Key" value="" id="Secondary_Key" onkeydown="colorbox();"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD align = right>FIRST<input type="text" size="35" maxlength="256" name="FIRST" value=""     id="FIRST"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD align = center><BUTTON NAME="submit" VALUE="Submit" TYPE="button" id="Submit"      onclick="check();">Submit</BUTTON></TD>
</TABLE>
</FORM> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Look into jquery toggle()

Answer (score 1):

The issue why your code is not working is because in the second function `colorbox`, you have `Secondary_key` instead of `Secondary_Key`. Look at the capital `K`.

Answer (score 0):

I know your code snippet is JS only but you put Jquery as tag so I will answer like so :

```
$('#Secondary_Key').keyup(function(e){
 if($(this).val()!=''){
   $(this).css({'background-color':'#fff'});
 }else{
   $(this).css({'background-color':'#f00'});
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function check() {     var value =
 document.getElementById("Secondary_Key").value;
     if (value == "") {
         document.getElementById("Secondary_Key").style.backgroundColor = "red";
     }
     else{
         document.getElementById("Secondary_Key").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    } } check();
```

fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/14/